# Issue with splitting data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run a code that would enable me to make a comparison between the current versus the past (last 6 months) socioeconomic situation and the voting preference in the last Spanish General Elections, which were in 2019.

If I run this code, I get the correct graphical output for all the parties that participated in the aforementioned elections:

```
#Analysis of Question 3 (current versus past situation of Spanish consumers, their perception of their own situation) in addition to Question 31a (facet of the respondents' voting preference)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

CIS_data_6 <- data.frame(
  CIS$RECUERDO,
  CIS$P3
)

dput(CIS_data_6)

CIS_data_6$CIS.P3 <- sub("\\(NO LEER\\) ", "", CIS_data_6$CIS.P3)
labs <- c("Mejor", "Igual", "N.C.", "N.S.", "Peor")
CIS_data_6$CIS.P3 <- factor(CIS_data_6$CIS.P3, labels = labs)

Recuerdo <- CIS_data_6$CIS.RECUERDO

Recuerdolabs <- c("N.P.", "PSOE", "PP", "VOX", "Unidas Podemos", "Ciudadanos")
cut_points <- c(0, 2, 1, 18, c(21, 6, 67), 4)

i <-c(Recuerdo, !is.na(cut_points))
Recuerdo_fac <- Recuerdolabs[i]
Recuerdo_fac[is.na(Recuerdo)] <- Recuerdolabs[length(Recuerdolabs)]
Recuerdo_fac <- factor(Recuerdo_fac, levels = Recuerdolabs)

CIS_data_6$CIS.RECUERDO <- Recuerdo


ggplot(CIS_data_6, aes(Recuerdo)) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation Based on Voting Preference") +
  ylab("Count") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ CIS.P3) +
  theme_bw()
```

However, this is graphically a mess, since there is all kind of minor parties which are of no relevance to my analysis.

The ones that I do want to outline are the big ones (plus abstention): "N.P." (Abstention), "PSOE", "PP", "VOX", "Unidas Podemos" and "Ciudadanos", with their corresponding encoding in the survey, which I denoted as `cut_points`: c(0, 2, 1, 18, c(21, 6, 67), 4).

Does anyone know how can I modify my code so that I can get to the desired output, i.e., to have a faceted graph (5 graphs, to be precise) saying "Mejor" ('Better'), "Peor" ('Worse'), "Igual" ('Same'), "N.S." ('Don't Know'), "N.C." ('Don't Answer') on the x-axis in each graph, and the political parties being located on the y-axis?

Many, many thanks in advance!

P.S. I am relatively new to this forum, so please, in case I have not expressed myself correctly or if there is any information lacking in my question, just let me know so, and I will be happy to provide it.

**EDIT**

```
dput(CIS_data_6)
```

is, as follows:

```
structure(list(CIS.RECUERDO = structure(c(2L, 2L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 15L, 15L, 2L, 26L, NA, 28L, 28L, 26L, 2L, NA, 13L, 2L, 27L, 
2L, 15L, 1L, 27L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 15L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 2L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 24L, 1L, 15L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 3L, NA, 
1L, NA, 27L, 1L, 27L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 28L, NA, 15L, 24L, 23L, 27L, 
23L, 28L, 1L, 23L, 3L, 1L, 21L, 26L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 
15L, 15L, 2L, 28L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 23L, 
1L, 28L, 27L, 1L, 28L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 15L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 15L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 23L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 27L, 27L, NA, 
28L, 26L, 21L, 3L, 28L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 26L, 1L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 28L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 
NA, 28L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 15L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 
26L, 28L, 1L, 28L, 3L, 1L, 13L, 26L, 15L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 26L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 23L, 13L, 2L, 
27L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 27L, 
1L, 28L, 15L, 15L, 13L, 21L, 28L, 13L, NA, 27L, 1L, 23L, 2L, 
28L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 27L, 24L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 
13L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 15L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 15L, 24L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 23L, 25L, 28L, 26L, 1L, 27L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 
13L, 15L, 23L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 25L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 26L, 2L, NA, 
26L, 25L, 25L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 13L, 15L, 23L, 26L, 2L, 1L, 24L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 28L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 24L, 28L, 1L, 
15L, 2L, 28L, 25L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 27L, 15L, 28L, 2L, 28L, 23L, 22L, 
1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 28L, NA, 21L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 1L, 27L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 26L, 1L, 26L, 24L, 1L, 13L, 26L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 24L, 
27L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 23L, 26L, 15L, 2L, 
2L, 15L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 26L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 26L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 23L, 1L, 3L, 26L, 23L, 
15L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 15L, 23L, 26L, 1L, 13L, 15L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 26L, 
15L, 2L, 25L, 1L, 26L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 15L, 15L, 28L, 
26L, 2L, 3L, 15L, 22L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 28L, 13L, 
26L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 1L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
23L, 26L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 24L, 1L, 28L, 27L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 25L, 1L, 
13L, 1L, 26L, 13L, NA, 3L, 28L, 15L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 26L, 3L, 25L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 28L, 25L, 26L, 2L, 28L, 27L, 
1L, 2L, 24L, 27L, 23L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 27L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
25L, 13L, 28L, 22L, 2L, 23L, 28L, 27L, NA, 28L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 
2L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 22L, 26L, 2L, NA, 28L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 13L, 2L, 
27L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 15L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 15L, 
2L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 15L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 
28L, 3L, 27L, 13L, 24L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 25L, 23L, 2L, 
26L, 24L, 15L, 15L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
15L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 21L, 15L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 26L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
26L, 28L, 1L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 
13L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 26L, NA, 2L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 15L, NA, 22L, 
26L, 28L, 26L, 28L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 28L, 
28L, 3L, 27L, 1L, 1L, NA, 26L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 26L, 
3L, 28L, 25L, 28L, 15L, 1L, 26L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 1L, 15L, 26L, 
1L, 8L, NA, 2L, 2L, 13L, 28L, 27L, 1L, 23L, 2L, 28L, 24L, 2L, 
2L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 1L, NA, NA, 26L, 3L, 3L, 24L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 24L, 15L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 26L, 28L, 
28L, 26L, 1L, 15L, 15L, NA, 2L, 15L, 27L, 28L, 2L, 26L, 24L, 
28L, 26L, 23L, 26L, 1L, 26L, 23L, 26L, 2L, 27L, 13L, 28L, 27L, 
24L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 26L, 26L, 15L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 15L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 2L, NA, 24L, 15L, 26L, 24L, 27L, 
28L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 23L, 1L, 
2L, 28L, 24L, NA, 13L, 2L, 26L, 3L, 25L, 1L, NA, 3L, 26L, 1L, 
25L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 15L, 26L, 15L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 23L, 2L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 23L, 28L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 
NA, 2L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 24L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 25L, 3L, 2L, 26L, 
13L, 2L, 28L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 27L, 15L, 2L, 25L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 
28L, 26L, 21L, 27L, 26L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 28L, 15L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 27L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 21L, 13L, 2L, 
13L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 28L, 24L, 24L, 2L, 24L, 28L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 15L, NA, 2L, 27L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 1L, 
27L, 1L, 28L, 26L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 23L, 24L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 28L, 25L, 
28L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 15L, 21L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 24L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 23L, 28L, 23L, 28L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 28L, NA, 13L, 2L, 
2L, NA, 28L, 1L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 21L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 28L, 
2L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 26L, 24L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 15L, 2L, 22L, 
27L, 26L, 26L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 
2L, 15L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 27L, 1L, 2L, 22L, 1L, 27L, 2L, 13L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 15L, 27L, 28L, 
15L, 3L, 28L, 28L, 15L, 26L, NA, 2L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 
28L, 13L, 28L, 25L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 26L, 28L, 26L, 2L, 
15L, 26L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 26L, 15L, 26L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 3L, 28L, 2L, 26L, 13L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 3L, 
15L, NA, 2L, NA, 26L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 27L, 21L, 
4L, 6L, 1L, 22L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 4L, 28L, 27L, NA, 26L, 6L, 6L, 
2L, 6L, 28L, 7L, 2L, 26L, 27L, NA, 2L, 26L, 2L, 26L, 28L, 4L, 
2L, 27L, 6L, 3L, 24L, 27L, 2L, 2L, NA, 23L, 28L, 3L, 27L, 1L, 
2L, 27L, 26L, 24L, NA, 27L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 27L, NA, 
2L, 2L, NA, 26L, 4L, 6L, NA, 28L, 26L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 24L, 23L, 
7L, 2L, 25L, 27L, 2L, 4L, 28L, NA, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 6L, 
26L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 2L, NA, 28L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 27L, 
2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 28L, NA, 2L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
3L, 2L, 26L, 27L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, NA, 6L, 26L, 24L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
28L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 7L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 6L, NA, NA, 28L, 
6L, 26L, 2L, 4L, 24L, 26L, 2L, 1L, 21L, 28L, 7L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 
2L, 27L, 26L, 2L, 4L, 26L, 2L, 1L, 27L, 26L, 7L, 28L, 26L, 28L, 
27L, 3L, NA, 27L, 28L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 26L, 2L, 7L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 26L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 27L, 26L, 
27L, 6L, 2L, 26L, 13L, 6L, 2L, 23L, 23L, 4L, 26L, 28L, 3L, 28L, 
22L, 26L, 1L, 6L, 26L, 27L, 6L, 27L, 2L, 6L, 21L, 4L, 6L, 28L, 
28L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 21L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 23L, 27L, 4L, NA, 
27L, 22L, 4L, 6L, 26L, 26L, 6L, 27L, 27L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 26L, 6L, 
4L, 13L, NA, 24L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 28L, 3L, 3L, 6L, NA, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 23L, 2L, 4L, 28L, 28L, 3L, 28L, 
28L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 28L, 6L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 26L, 6L, 2L, 
28L, 2L, 25L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 27L, 28L, NA, NA, 27L, 28L, 6L, 4L, 
28L, 26L, 6L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 28L, 6L, 2L, 23L, 26L, 2L, 
7L, 2L, 4L, NA, 2L, 27L, 7L, 26L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 6L, 27L, 23L, 
26L, 22L, 6L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 28L, 24L, 27L, 6L, 
27L, NA, 27L, 6L, 6L, 26L, 2L, 28L, 7L, NA, 26L, 26L, 7L, 6L, 
24L, 2L, 6L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 2L, 23L, 6L, 
6L, 27L, 25L, 21L, 6L, NA, 2L, 28L, 4L, 27L, 23L, 1L, 23L, 6L, 
13L, 7L, 2L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 24L, 6L, 2L, 25L, 26L, 4L, 26L, 26L, 
23L, 1L, 28L, 4L, 2L, 27L, 7L, 28L, 4L, 27L, NA, 6L, 7L, 15L, 
26L, 28L, 15L, 26L, 24L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 23L, 28L, 3L, 2L, 15L, 24L, 28L, 15L, 
2L, 15L, 26L, 15L, 28L, 13L, 2L, NA, 28L, 2L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 
2L, 2L, 28L, 3L, NA, 2L, 28L, 15L, 27L, 24L, 3L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 
15L, 28L, 15L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 24L, 2L, 13L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 15L, 
NA, 28L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 13L, 15L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 26L, 
26L, 2L, 28L, 23L, 13L, 1L, 27L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 22L, 
2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 23L, 2L, 26L, 24L, 28L, 27L, 2L, 26L, NA, 2L, 
27L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 25L, 2L, 2L, NA, 26L, 24L, 23L, 2L, 
2L, 26L, 24L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 28L, 
26L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 27L, 24L, 28L, 24L, 1L, 24L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 
15L, 2L, 23L, 27L, 26L, 1L, 24L, 24L, 27L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 1L, 
2L, 21L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 27L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L, 27L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 
2L, 13L, 26L, 1L, 1L, NA, 28L, 13L, 15L, 26L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, NA, 26L, 15L, 26L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 1L, 
25L, 26L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 
2L, 23L, 24L, 15L, NA, 2L, 15L, 28L, 15L, 28L, 28L, 2L, 23L, 
13L, 24L, 2L, 27L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 28L, NA, 3L, 1L, 15L, 2L, 28L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 13L, 26L, 26L, 15L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 
26L, 2L, 25L, 26L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 13L, NA, 28L, 1L, 13L, 28L, 1L, 
13L, 23L, 23L, 1L, 2L, NA, 28L, 3L, 28L, 13L, 28L, 26L, 15L, 
3L, 28L, 9L, 26L, 28L, 23L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 28L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 
28L, 1L, 25L, 2L, NA, 26L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 28L, 2L, 23L, 13L, 28L, 
28L, 1L, 3L, 26L, 3L, 28L, 25L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 2L, 
27L, 1L, 21L, NA, 26L, 28L, 15L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 3L, 
26L, 3L, 23L, 27L, 3L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 21L, 13L, 27L, 2L, 24L, 24L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 13L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 28L, 25L, 
21L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 27L, 24L, 28L, 26L, 1L, 26L, 
24L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 24L, 24L, 21L, 
2L, 3L, 25L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 27L, 24L, 28L, NA, 26L, 24L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 26L, 1L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 27L, 26L, 
1L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 26L, 26L, NA, 1L, 
28L, 26L, 24L, 1L, 26L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L, 26L, 2L, 28L, 1L, 
28L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 27L, 24L, 2L, 25L, 1L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 
23L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 24L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 23L, 
24L, 27L, 21L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 24L, 23L, 24L, 2L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 
13L, 27L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 27L, 23L, 1L, 24L, 2L, 13L, NA, 2L, 
26L, 25L, 2L, 26L, 28L, 2L, 24L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 23L, 15L, 26L, 
2L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 
13L, 26L, 1L, 27L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 28L, 15L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 
28L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 27L, 2L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 1L, 24L, 
28L, 2L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 28L, 26L, 23L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 
23L, 15L, 13L, 21L, 15L, 23L, 1L, 27L, 27L, 2L, 21L, 15L, 15L, 
1L, 2L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 26L, 23L, 2L, 
15L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 26L, 3L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 26L, 1L, 24L, 3L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 26L, 15L, 26L, 
2L, 26L, 22L, NA, 1L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 28L, 13L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 15L, NA, 2L, 24L, 26L, 22L, 28L, 1L, 13L, 13L, NA, 3L, 8L, 
21L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 26L, NA, 2L, 28L, 3L, 28L, NA, 23L, 
26L, 15L, 15L, 2L, NA, 15L, 1L, 3L, 15L, 26L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 24L, 2L, 24L, 25L, 3L, 28L, 2L, 15L, 1L, NA, 
28L, 3L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 22L, 15L, 3L, 24L, 26L, 
2L, 24L, 1L, 24L, 3L, 13L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 28L, 24L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 2L, 22L, NA, 1L, 
2L, 26L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 
28L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 26L, NA, 15L, 24L, NA, 1L, 27L, 2L, 
2L, 27L, 27L, 2L, 23L, 2L, 28L, 13L, 2L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 28L, 
27L, 2L, 27L, 15L, 13L, 26L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 26L, 1L, NA, 26L, 
28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L, NA, 28L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 25L, 2L, 1L, 
15L, 27L, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, 26L, 1L, 13L, 26L, NA, NA, 2L, 23L, 
27L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 25L, 3L, 26L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 24L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 28L, 15L, 15L, 26L, 22L, 28L, 2L, 
28L, 1L, 24L, 28L, 28L, 15L, 15L, 3L, 15L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 1L, 
24L, 27L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 28L, 13L, NA, 1L, 1L, 28L, 
28L, 2L, 26L, 13L, 28L, 24L, 2L, 13L, 15L, NA, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 27L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 1L, 26L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 
13L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 28L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 13L, 
26L, 1L, 28L, 1L, NA, 2L, 26L, 3L, 23L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 28L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 15L, 2L, NA, 23L, 3L, 15L, 2L, 
28L, 23L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 28L, NA, 2L, 28L, 22L, 
13L, 2L, 27L, 26L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 26L, 
15L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 24L, 23L, 13L, 15L, 26L, 1L, 26L, 21L, 23L, 
2L, 13L, 26L, 2L, 26L, 3L, 13L, 28L, 1L, 13L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 
2L, 27L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 28L, 27L, 13L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 26L, NA, 
21L, 3L, 27L, 15L, 1L, 28L, 28L, 23L, 3L, 23L, 3L, 24L, 9L, 2L, 
9L, 23L, 27L, 26L, 24L, 26L, 2L, 28L, NA, 26L, NA, 2L, 28L, 2L, 
24L, 28L, 9L, 27L, 24L, 6L, 13L, NA, 2L, 24L, 24L, 22L, 28L, 
9L, 24L, NA, 24L, 24L, 2L, 24L, 23L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 2L, 
8L, 1L, 26L, 22L, 2L, 23L, 1L, 27L, 22L, 2L, 26L, 15L, 2L, 24L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 26L, 26L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 
25L, 8L, 15L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 9L, NA, 23L, 26L, 9L, 9L, 26L, 
9L, 26L, 9L, 13L, 8L, 25L, 8L, 1L, 28L, 23L, 9L, 2L, 27L, 8L, 
28L, 15L, 9L, 24L, 9L, 28L, 26L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 28L, 
15L, 8L, 15L, NA, 2L, 27L, 2L, NA, 28L, 28L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 15L, 
8L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 26L, NA, NA, 27L, 28L, 9L, 26L, 15L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, NA, 26L, 26L, 8L, 15L, NA, 26L, 8L, 27L, 9L, 27L, 28L, 
26L, 28L, 8L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 15L, NA, 9L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 9L, 
28L, 28L, 9L, 9L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 23L, 25L, 3L, 2L, 15L, 28L, 26L, 1L, 28L, 26L, 23L, 2L, 
1L, 25L, 26L, 24L), levels = c("PP     ", "PSOE   ", "Ciudadanos     ", 
"En Com├║ Podem ", "M├®s Comprom├¡s", "ERC    ", "JxCat  ", 
"EAJ-PNV", "EH Bildu       ", "CCa-NC ", "Na+    ", "PACMA  ", 
"VOX    ", "CUP    ", "Unidas Podemos ", "BNG    ", "PRC    ", 
"M├ís Pa├¡s     ", "En Com├║n-Unidas Podemos       ", 
"Teruel Existe  ", "Nulo   ", "No ten├¡a derecho a voto       ", 
"No ten├¡a edad ", "Otros partidos ", "En blanco      ", "No vot├│       ", 
"No recuerda    ", "N.C.   "), class = "factor"), CIS.P3 = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), levels = c("Mejor", "(NO LEER) Igual", "Peor", "N.S.", 
"N.C."), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2787L))
```

Comment: Is `CIS` your data? Its unfortunately impossible to run this without having the `dput` of that data included. Paste whatever `dput(CIS_data_6)` spits out into your question.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment, @ShawnHemelstrand! I have just done this. Please, see my edited question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the job:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(labelled)

CIS = read_spss("CISData.sav") %>%
  mutate(
    P3 = to_factor(P3),
    RECUERDO = to_factor(RECUERDO)) %>%
  mutate(P3 = sub("\\(NO LEER\\) ", "", P3))

include = c("PSOE", "PP", "VOX", "Unidas Podemos", "Ciudadanos")

CISb = CIS %>%
  filter(RECUERDO %in% include) %>%
  group_by(RECUERDO, P3) %>%
  tally() %>%
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n))

plot2 = ggplot(CISb, aes(x = pct, y = RECUERDO)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~P3, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Percentage of Party's Voters in Each Response", y = "Voting Preference in 2019 General Elections",
    title = "Current VS Past Individual Situation Based on Voting Preference")
plot2
```